# How to parse 10-Q reports from EDGAR API in python?

Tags: python, xml, edgar

I'm trying to use EDGAR API to retrieve 10-Q for any given company (corresponding to the CIK value provided.) This code retrieves the most recent 10-Q for Tesla. There are about 30 methods attached to this object, such as keys, values, items, and text_content. Text_content appears to be the only one that does not return an empty list `[]`. However, text is not easy to parse because the 10-Q varies considerably from one company to another.

Undoubtedly, someone will comment: Why did I set `no_of_documents=2`? If this parameter is set to 1, the wrong document (not 10-Q) will be returned. With any parameter over 1, actual 10-Qs will be retrieved. I have no idea why the API behaves this way.

```py
from edgar import Company
def func(cik):
    company = Company("",cik)
    tree = company.get_all_filings(filing_type="10-Q")        
    documents = Company.get_documents(tree,no_of_documents=2)
    return documents[0]
    
test = func('0001318605')
```

What I'd like to do is (A) print out raw XML to take a peek at its underlying structure, then parse with either `xmltodict` or `xml.etree.ElementTree`. However, I'm receiving the following errors.

Using ET

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ET.parse(test)
>>>
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HtmlElement
```

Using XMLtoDict

```py
import xmltodict
xmltodict.parse(test)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'HtmlElement'
```

Again my goal is to search for navigate the XML content, however, without knowing what the tags are, I'm a bit stuck. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse `test`; you can use xpath methods directly on it. For example:

```
test.xpath('//entity/segment/explicitmember/text()')
```

Outputs:

```
 'tsla:OperatingLeaseVehiclesMember',
 'tsla:OperatingLeaseVehiclesMember',
 'tsla:SolarEnergySystemsMember',
 'tsla:SolarEnergySystemsMember',
 'tsla:AutomotiveSegmentMember',
 'tsla:AutomotiveSegmentMember',
```

etc.
and

```
test.xpath('//context/period/instant/text()')
```

outputs:

```
 ['2020-07-20',
 '2020-06-30',
 '2019-12-31',
 '2020-06-30',
 '2019-12-31',
```

and so on.

Good luck; parsing xbrl filings is not an easy task...

Comment: Thanks! Question, how did you find/come up with valid xpath inputs...ie did you use dev tools on Google Chrome or something?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 No, going through the dev tools for something like this will turn your hair white before its time, although it's good for getting a feel for the structure generally. One way to get a sense, is to try `text.xpath('//*')` and see what it looks like. Not that it will prevent your hair from turning white eventually...